# Javascript trigger on "KeyPress" and "Paste"

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript that checks if a field equals to 15 characters, and if not the submit button is greyed out. This works perfetcly if i type in 15 characters manually, but not if i paste 15 characters. How can i make it check even when content is pasted in the field?

Can i make it check for characters periodicly (seconds) or is there a function for "check on paste"?

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled","disabled");
$('input[name="item_meta[1234]"]').keypress(function() { //change # to the ID of your field
        if (document.getElementById("field_ygtw9u").value.length < 14) { //disable submit if "no" is selected
              $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled","disabled");
        } else { //enable the submit button
              $('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
  });
});
</script>

<form>
<div id="frm_field_1234_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_required_field frm_top_container">
<label class="frm_primary_label">Minimun 15 char:
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
</label>
<input type="text" id="field_ygtw9u" name="item_meta[1234]" value=""  maxlength="15" class="required"/>

<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: What u mean? Thats all the code there is. I'll add my HTML above as well if that helps?

Comment: Try'd the onpaste event? `<input type="text" onpaste="some_js_code_or_function()" />`. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3j497/

Comment: `keypress` will not fire if `backspace` is pressed in chrome and ie

Comment: Got it, check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333668/javascript-trigger-on-keypress-and-paste/15334278#15334278)!

Comment: for angular users see [ngPaste](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPaste).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change `keypress` to `keyup` and it should work.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Now it validates the input on both manual and pasted inputs. Thank you! Went for this solution since it's the easiest and it worked out in both IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Tested, working. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fnkr/MXnuk/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkInput() {
        if (document.getElementById("field_ygtw9u").value.length < 14) { //disable submit if "no" is selected
                $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            } else { //enable the submit button
                $('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('input[name="item_meta[1234]"]').bind("input", function () { //change # to the ID of your field
            checkInput();    
        });

        $('input[name="item_meta[1234]"]').bind("propertychange", function () { //change # to the ID of your field
            checkInput();
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
    <div id="frm_field_1234_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_required_field frm_top_container">
        <label class="frm_primary_label">Minimun 15 char: <span class="frm_required"></span>

        </label>
        <input type="text" id="field_ygtw9u" name="item_meta[1234]" value="" maxlength="15"
        class="required" />
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
var $submit = $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled","disabled");
$('input[name="item_meta[1234]"]').keyup(function() { //change # to the ID of your field
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length < 14) { //disable submit if "no" is selected
        $submit.attr("disabled","disabled");
    } else { //enable the submit button
        $submit.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });

$('#field_ygtw9u').on('paste', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        if ($this.val().length < 14) { //disable submit if "no" is selected
            $submit.attr("disabled","disabled");
        } else { //enable the submit button
            $submit.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3j497/4/)

Don't use `keypress` event since it won't be fired while pressing `backspace` in IE/Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You should use `propertychange` (IE) and `input` events. [**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SBxfz/)

```
$('input[name="item_meta[1234]"]').bind("input", function() { //change # to the ID of your field
    if (document.getElementById("field_ygtw9u").value.length < 14) { //disable submit if "no" is selected
          $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled","disabled");
    } else { //enable the submit button
          $('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});

$('input[name="item_meta[1234]"]').bind("propertychange", function() { //change # to the ID of your field
    if (document.getElementById("field_ygtw9u").value.length < 14) { //disable submit if "no" is selected
          $('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled","disabled");
    } else { //enable the submit button
          $('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```