# Allow only number in JS and verify past

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that only allows number in keypress how can i change this function ou method to call, so when i do ctrl+v verify too the values?

```
function isNumberKey(evt, obj) {
    var containsDot = obj.value.indexOf(".");
    var nrDecimals = Decimals(obj.value, ".");

    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 8 || charCode == 9) {
        return true;
    } else if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        if (charCode == 46 && containsDot < 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    if (nrDecimals > 2) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I call it this way

> onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,this);"

Comment: possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333668/javascript-trigger-on-keypress-and-paste

Comment: apart from copy-paste, a user can also drag-drop text, it would be better if u can validate on form submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want numbers in your input, you could do something like this:

```
onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/, '');"
```

This replaces all non-number characters from the value. This does about the same as your whole function does, plus it works with the paste.

You need to change `onkeypress` to `onkeyup`.

---

For the full solution you need to switch to more complex code. As one of the comment below says, you can rightclick->paste aswell. This will not catch that. You need to bind multiple event (keypress, keyup, click are examples of events) to that one input. If you're lucky, `focus` will catch it (if rightclick blurs it, and after paste it focusses).

Comment: "plus it works with the paste." - well, it's [not working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/LRa8m/). I think it should be `onkeyup`

Comment: Wasn't really sure about the past, thats why I suggested the change to keyup. Fixed that :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery. Change the below code as per your requirement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#id")
           .bind('copy', function(e) {
                alert('copying!');
            })
            .bind('paste', function(e) {
                alert('pasting!');
            })
            .bind('cut', function(e) {
                alert('cut!');
            });
    });
```

If you want to use plane javascript. I think below will work, but not sure about the browser compatibility.

```
<input type="text" onpaste="callFunc()" />
```

Comment: I added the chaining. It was not needed in your code, but I thought it was a good idea to highlight the possibility for this user and others, for it is a powerfull strength in jQuery